# Software (Other than PS) to align images?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, software-recommendation, blending

I shot two panorama at different times of the day:

My goal is to align them so I can do exposure blending. I tried doing so in Photoshop but the results are not very good. Photoshop allows very little control over the alignment process.

Does anyone know if there are softwares out there that would allow me to align these images using specific points that I pick?

Comment: I would also try PTGui, it allows you to select points when aligning photos.

Comment: Both of these are panorama tools. How will they actually help with aligning different panoramas?

Comment: These images have different vantage points, that makes the task near impossible. What i would do here is lots and lots of cloning.

Answer (score 1):

Panoramas which are put together of discrete shots have often complex distortions generated by the panorama stitcher when it tried to crush the seams to fit. If the panoramas taken in day and evening do not have otherwise identical sets of shots except the light, the panoramas probably have totally different distortions - for ex. because the lens apertures are different if that wasn't taken into the account.

Worse: Camera placements and positions can be different.

You must force at first your panoramas geometrically identical with puppet warp - a manual job. It may succeed if you have lens distortion correction in use and the different daytime shots are taken with close enough camera placements and positions.

After having geometrically identical panoramas you can create a HDR -combination. If you have only 2 panoramas it can succeed by masking and adjusting the colors.

So, before jumping to a different program try Photoshop once more. Warp the panorama versions to match geometrically and use  adjustment layers and layer masks to make an uniform enough combination. An example:

[image]

The top layer Curves 2 increases the contrast except the sky. Layer Curves 1 tries to remove fog from the bright version. There's "the next layer only"-switch = ON.

[image]

Distorting the brighter version manually to match was not especially difficult due the unsharpness of your attached images. I guess you have also high resolution versions. They need much more care. The adjustments and masks were inserted by trial and error.

I do not claim my version is perfect, clever software which makes it better can well exist.